# Requesting 500 records on the `search` connection exceeds the `first` limit of 100 records in graphql

Tags: pagination, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to fetch all the repositories with the searched keyword. There are about 500 repositories for the searched result, but I was able to retrieve only 100 as that's the limit, is there any way to retrieve all 500.

```
query {
    rateLimit{
        cost
        remaining
        resetAt
    }

search(query: "-js created:>2015-01-01 language:JavaScript", type:REPOSITORY, first: 500){ 
    repositoryCount
    pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
        startCursor
    }
    edges {
        node {
            ... on Repository {
                name
                url
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting the message

> "Requesting 500 records on the `search` connection exceeds the `first`
>   limit of 100 records.", and
>         "type": "EXCESSIVE_PAGINATION"

Comment: limit for free access, pay for more

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this, was able to list all repositories but not all at once.

There is a field called 'endCursor', when you run the query for first: 100, you will get some value for endCursor , then in the search query provide that endCursor value for 'after' field as below :

```
    search(query: "-js created:>2015-01-01 language:JavaScript", 
    type:REPOSITORY, first: 100, after: "endCursor value")
```

By this you can get next 100 repositories, likewise do for remaining repositories to be listed.